# Why two unbond transactions is becoming an unbonding transaction?

Tags: staking

I send two unbond transactions, but the explore is showing that is an unbonding transaction?

https://westend.subscan.io/account/5Crhv9SAQsvtnMDNQZekEk9oQEcSjWepdguCA3NP9VKddkr4?tab=unbonding

Answer (score 0):

That's the design.

If you want to participate in staking, you need to stake. And you can not unstake immediately.

For Kusama, you need to wait 7 days. Polkadot 28 days.

Why? I could just say, due to the economic model.

E.g there is price volatility, you can not unstake and sell the tokens immediately.